# Singular cohomology with compact support

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then for any $n \geq0$ is $H_c^n(X) \cong {\tilde H^n}({X^ + })$? ($H_c^n(X)$ is the Singular cohomology with compact support and $X^+$ is the one-point compactification of $X$)